# How do I click this sign in button using python selenium chrome driver:

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to select and click the sign in button using python selenium chrome driver however I am unsure how to define the button:

```
<button class="Wizard__AccountActionButton-mlu9la-10 fCdYqg flex justify-center items-center  font-din">Sign in</button>
```

Comment: Try one of the google search results: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-click-a-button-on-webpage-using-selenium/ https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/click-element-method-selenium-python/ https://pythonspot.com/selenium-click-button/

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **Sign in** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.flex.justify-center.items-center.font-din").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class, 'flex justify-center items-center  font-din') and text()='Sign in']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.flex.justify-center.items-center.font-din"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class, 'flex justify-center items-center  font-din') and text()='Sign in']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```